# Regex - special character surrounded by letters or space

Tags: regex

I want to check that an underscore is obligatorily between two letters or spaces.

For example :

"-ayui" : not good

"jjdk-jk" : good

"hd -sdjh" : good

"fgggdf-" : not good

"hjhfs - jgkd" : good

" kf8-1dd" : not good

Can you help me ?

Thanks very much !

Comment: If only small letters are there in expression. You can try following regular expression. `/"[a-z\s]+-[a-z\s]+"/g`

Comment: You can try [`^[a-z]+\s*-\s*[a-z]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/4i5W31/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your example data, I think you mean hyphen instead of underscore.

If that is the case, you could use [`^[a-z]+\s*-\s*[a-z]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/4i5W31/1) to match:

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- One or more characters `[a-z]+`
- Zero or more times a whitespace `\s*`
- Match a hyphen `-`
- Zero or more times a whitespace `\s*`
- One or more characters `[a-z]+`
- Until the end of the string `$`